# D3 Tree Layout Not Collapsing

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I previously asked a similar question before, however it seemed that I wasn't being precise enough about my question - hopefully this is.

Many examples of the Tree Layout format their  hierarchy data set as this: https://gist.github.com/tchaymore/1249394#file-math_map_compact-json

However I wanted to change the "children" node in the json to "children1" for example

```
       var flare = {

"Name": "Example",
"children1": [


{
 "BName":"Ja",   
 "Email":"",
 "children1":[
 {

    "NickName":"NC",
    "id":2

 }
],

}
 ]};
```

When I had changed the name of that node, I then used the children function:

```
 var tree = d3.layout.tree()
.size([height, width])
.children(function(d) { return d.children1; });
```

After that I changed all of the "children" references to "children1" & so on.

However, now I have the problem of not being able to collapse the tree back into its parent. I've tried to use this example as a reference, but no luck: http://blog.pixelingene.com/2011/07/building-a-tree-diagram-in-d3-js/

Here's a example of my current problem: http://jsfiddle.net/mEyQW/1/

.. I apologize for the previous confusion

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get what you wanted to do with your `collapse()` function and the `_children1` but if you remove it, then everything works fine:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/mEyQW/2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I would like it to collapse back into its parent. On the example you have shown me, when I click "rick" the tree extends.